# RAID 10 software from the install with Centos 5.5

Tags: linux, centos, raid, raid10

I'm downloading right now the Centos 5 DVD.
Is there any way to install it on 4 HDs (2Tb)?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The graphical installer will let you create software RAID partitions, and then join them together into RAID sets.  Just make sure that you install GRUB on the hard disks other than the first one, so it'll still boot if the primary drive fails.  There's copious documentation for this online.